# How can I sort a TList in Delphi on an arbitrary property of the objects it contains?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have a TList.  It contains a collection of objects of the same type.  These objects are descended from a TPersistent, and have about 50 different published properties.

In my application, the user can issue a search of these objects, and the results of the search are displayed in a TDrawGrid, with the specific columns displayed being based on the properties being searched.  For example, if the user searches on 'invoice', an 'invoice' column is displayed in the results' grid.  I would like to be able to let the user sort this grid.  The kicker, of course, is that I wont know up front what columns are in the grid.

Normally to sort a TList, I'd just make a function, such as `SortOnName( p1, p2)`, and call the TList's `sort()` method.  I'd like to go one step further and find a way to pass a property name to the sort method and use RTTI to make the comparison.

I could, of course, make 50 different sort methods and just use that.  Or, set a variable globally or as part of the class doing all this work to indicate to the sorting method what to sort on.  But I was curious if any of the Delphi pro's out there had other ideas on how to implement this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Delphi 7 version**
Here's an example of how to achieve that. I used Delphi2010 to implement it but it should work in Delphi7 at least as I used TypInfo unit directly.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ListBox1: TListBox;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FList: TList;
    procedure DoSort(PropName: String);
    procedure DoDisplay(PropName: String);
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses
  TypInfo;

var
  PropertyName: String;

type
  TPerson = class
  private
    FName: String;
    FAge: Integer;
  published
  public
    constructor Create(Name: String; Age: Integer);
  published
    property Name: String read FName;
    property Age: Integer read FAge;
  end;

{ TPerson }

constructor TPerson.Create(Name: String; Age: Integer);
begin
  FName := Name;
  FAge := Age;
end;

function ComparePersonByPropertyName(P1, P2: Pointer): Integer;
var
  propValueP1, propValueP2: Variant;
begin
  propValueP1 := GetPropValue(P1, PropertyName, False);
  propValueP2 := GetPropValue(P2, PropertyName, False);

  if VarCompareValue(propValueP1, propValueP2) = vrEqual then begin
    Result :=  0;
  end else if VarCompareValue(propValueP1, propValueP2) = vrGreaterThan then begin
    Result :=  1;
  end else begin
    Result := -1;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FList := TList.Create;
  FList.Add(TPerson.Create('Zed', 10));
  FList.Add(TPerson.Create('John', 20));
  FList.Add(TPerson.Create('Mike', 30));
  FList.Add(TPerson.Create('Paul', 40));
  FList.Add(TPerson.Create('Albert', 50));
  FList.Add(TPerson.Create('Barbara', 60));
  FList.Add(TPerson.Create('Christian', 70));

  Edit1.Text := 'Age';

  DoSort('Age'); // Sort by age
  DoDisplay('Age');
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DoSort(Edit1.Text);
  DoDisplay(Edit1.Text);
end;

procedure TForm1.DoSort(PropName: String);
begin
  PropertyName := PropName;
  FList.Sort(ComparePersonByPropertyName);
end;

procedure TForm1.DoDisplay(PropName: String);
var
  i: Integer;
  strPropValue: String;
begin
  ListBox1.Items.Clear;

  for i := 0 to FList.Count - 1 do begin
    strPropValue := GetPropValue(FList[i], PropName, False);
    ListBox1.Items.Add(strPropValue);
  end;
end;

end.
```

BTW, I used a simple form with a *listbox*, an *edit* and a *button*. The listbox shows the contents of the list (FList) sorted. The button is used to sort the list according to what the user has typed in the editbox.

**Delphi 2010 version** (uses references to methods)

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    ListBox1: TListBox;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FList: TList;
    FPropertyName: String; { << }
    procedure DoSort(PropName: String);
    procedure DoDisplay(PropName: String);
    function CompareObjectByPropertyName(P1, P2: Pointer): Integer; { << }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses
  TypInfo;

type
  TPerson = class
  private
    FName: String;
    FAge: Integer;
  published
  public
    constructor Create(Name: String; Age: Integer);
  published
    property Name: String read FName;
    property Age: Integer read FAge;
  end;

{ TPerson }

constructor TPerson.Create(Name: String; Age: Integer);
begin
  FName := Name;
  FAge := Age;
end;

/// This version uses a method to do the sorting and therefore can use a field of the form,
/// no more ugly global variable.
/// See below (DoSort) if you want to get rid of the field also ;)
function TForm2.CompareObjectByPropertyName(P1, P2: Pointer): Integer; { << }
var
  propValueP1, propValueP2: Variant;
begin
  propValueP1 := GetPropValue(P1, FPropertyName, False);
  propValueP2 := GetPropValue(P2, FPropertyName, False);

  if VarCompareValue(propValueP1, propValueP2) = vrEqual then begin
    Result :=  0;
  end else if VarCompareValue(propValueP1, propValueP2) = vrGreaterThan then begin
    Result :=  1;
  end else begin
    Result := -1;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FList := TList.Create;
  FList.Add(TPerson.Create('Zed', 10));
  FList.Add(TPerson.Create('John', 20));
  FList.Add(TPerson.Create('Mike', 30));
  FList.Add(TPerson.Create('Paul', 40));
  FList.Add(TPerson.Create('Albert', 50));
  FList.Add(TPerson.Create('Barbara', 60));
  FList.Add(TPerson.Create('Christian', 70));

  Edit1.Text := 'Age';

  DoSort('Age'); // Sort by age
  DoDisplay('Age');
end;

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DoSort(Edit1.Text);
  DoDisplay(Edit1.Text);
end;

procedure TForm2.DoSort(PropName: String);
begin
  FPropertyName := PropName; { << }
  FList.SortList(CompareObjectByPropertyName); { << }

  /// The code above could be written with a lambda, and without CompareObjectByPropertyName
  /// using FPropertyName, and by using a closure thus referring to PropName directly.

  /// Below is the equivalent code that doesn't make use of FPropertyName. The code below
  /// could be commented out completely and just is there to show an alternative approach.
  FList.SortList(
    function (P1, P2: Pointer): Integer
    var
      propValueP1, propValueP2: Variant;
    begin
      propValueP1 := GetPropValue(P1, PropName, False);
      propValueP2 := GetPropValue(P2, PropName, False);

      if VarCompareValue(propValueP1, propValueP2) = vrEqual then begin
        Result :=  0;
      end else if VarCompareValue(propValueP1, propValueP2) = vrGreaterThan then begin
        Result :=  1;
      end else begin
        Result := -1; /// This is a catch anything else, even if the values cannot be compared
      end;
    end);
  /// Inline anonymous functions (lambdas) make the code less readable but
  /// have the advantage of "capturing" local variables (creating a closure)
end;

procedure TForm2.DoDisplay(PropName: String);
var
  i: Integer;
  strPropValue: String;
begin
  ListBox1.Items.Clear;

  for i := 0 to FList.Count - 1 do begin
    strPropValue := GetPropValue(FList[i], PropName, False);
    ListBox1.Items.Add(strPropValue);
  end;
end;

end.
```

I marked with `{ << }` the main changes.

Comment: Oh, if you have Delphi2010 then you can use a lambda to get rid of the global variable by turning ComparePersonByPropertyName into a method and instead of Sort() you have to use SortList()

Comment: Thanks Trinidad.  Thats probably the approach I'll end up using (the code above).  I think the only other option is to create a descendent TList and implement my own quick sort that would accept a property name parameter, or at least accept a method (procedure of object) as a parameter to the sort method, rather than just a procedure.

Answer (score 3):

Upgrade to Delphi >= 2009, and then you can use anonymous methods to pass a function declaration directly into TList.Sort.

An example can be found at 
http://delphi.about.com/od/delphitips2009/qt/sort-generic.htm

I don't know of any other way, other than the methods you describe in your question.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure that would do the trick since the sorting function still needs a way of knowing what property to sort on, which is only known at runtime.  (I do have D2010, btw)

Comment: But you would pass that known-at-runtime property as a parameter.  Write code that sorts by something, and then tell it which one that something is at runtime.

Comment: I see the problem yes, you might have to do a case statement to know what to compare in the anonymous method, e.g.

    MyList.Sort(TComparer<TMyObj>.Construct(
           function (const L, R: TMyObj): integer
           begin
             if Edit1 = 'Age' then result :=      CompareValue(L.Age, R.Age)
           end
           )) ;

Comment: Not a case statement actually.

Comment: Thanks for the assist Alan.  Its definately a little 'gotcha' with sorting.  I only need it in one place, otherwise I'd create a new TList descendent that implemented its own quicksort.  I mainly curious if there was a more elegant way to do what I wanted to do.